# PHP: using list() and each() to traverse multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, list, function, multidimensional-array, each

So, for a class assignment, I've constructed this receipt that uses a function to tally up the costs of three items and echo a grand total.  The catch is you have to put the specific values into the function to get the results you want, every time.

Here's the code:

```
<B>Checkout</B><br>
Below is a summary of the products you wish to purchase, along with totals:<br><br>
<?php
```

So, instead of putting the values in myself, my professor wants me to use a multi-dimensional array to pull the values from an already existing "database," using `list()` and `each()`.

```
$database = array(
    'Candle Holder' => array('Price' => '11.95','Shipping' => '0'),
    'Coffee Table' => array('Price' => '99.50','Shipping' => '0.10'),
    'Floor Lamp' => array('Price' => '44.99','Shipping' => '0.10')
);
```

This here prints out the values with a `print_r` command.

```
while(list($product,$price) = each($database)){
echo '<b>'.$product.'</b><br>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($database);
echo '</pre>';

} //end of while loop
```

Here's the function that tallies up the prices. I'm wanting to know how to use the `list()` and `each()` functions to pull from my 2D array and put them into the parameters.

```
function tally($product, $price, $shipping){

$tax = 0.08;
$total_price = $price;
$total_tax = $tax * $price;
$total_shipping = $shipping * $price;
$grand_total = ($total_price + $total_tax + $total_shipping);

return $grand_total;

} //end of function tally()

?>
<ul>
```

RIGHT HERE is where I'm having to put the data in myself, and she wants me to draw it from the array and plug it into the function.

```
<?php
$after_tally = tally('Candle Holder', 11.95, 0);
$after_tally += tally('Coffee Table', 99.50, 0.10);
$after_tally += tally('Floor Lamp', 44.99, 0.10);

?>
</ul>
<hr>
<br>
<B>Total (including tax and shipping): $<? echo number_format($after_tally, 2); ?></B>
```

I know that newer versions of PHP are trying to push the recent `foreach()` (I know nothing about using it) function, but my professor says it would be good practice to know the older, slower method too.

THANKS!

Comment: *I know nothing about using it* -- http://php.net/foreach -- start here.

Comment: Cool! Seems simple enough.  Kinda need to know more about the list and each things though.

Comment: your professor sounds like she has a lot of faith in you and it looks like you're really into learning.  do you really want one of us to just hand you the code?  start with... `foreach ($database as $index => $data) { print $index."<br/>"; print_r($data); print "<br/><br/>"; }`

Comment: Just to clarify, me asking this isn't cheating or anything like that. :-) She knows I come here to research.  It's difficult to get in touch with her at times, so I'd just as soon ask Stack as I would ask her.  It's an online, self-paced class, and I just got stumped, trying to figure this one out... I'll probably have to ask her anyway for more help or info about what she's wanting, cause the subject of traversing multi arrays with `list` and `each` seems unusually quiet online :-(